# useTransition in React Spring causes too many rerenders

Tags: reactjs, animation, transition, react-spring

I'm using `useTransition` from `react spring` to build a masonry-gridish display  of animated words for a blog. My work is heavily based on react spring's official codesandbox demo of a masonry grid which can be found here: https://codesandbox.io/embed/26mjowzpr

My work can be found here: https://codesandbox.io/s/qrzn-issue-2-david-byrne-8s7bo?file=/src/App.js:1267-1293

What you'll notice in my codesandbox, is that if you click on one of the little heads on the bottom, the transition occurs, but then the page will rerender about 20 times and I can't figure out why.

I think it has something to do with my invocation of `useTransition`, but am totally at a loss

```
  const leftTransitions = useTransition(leftGridItems, item => item.word, {
    from: ({ xy, width, height }) => {
      return {
        xy: [xOffset, yOffset],
        width,
        height,
        opacity: 0
      };
    },
    enter: ({ xy, width, height }) => ({ xy, width, height, opacity: 1 }),
    update: ({ xy, width, height }) => ({ xy, width, height }),
    leave: ({ xy, width, height }) => {
      return {
        xy: [xOffset, yOffset],
        opacity: 0
      };
    },
    config: { mass: 5, tension: 500, friction: 100 },
    trail: 25
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone's interested, this is no longer an issue if you update to v9. Details in the changelog here: https://www.react-spring.io/log

Comment: Not true. This problem still exists in version 9.